# handlebars template won't update to reflect the computed property after dynamically removing an entry

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

Here is the basic setup:

1. I bind an array of ember-data models to my handlebars template using a simple computed property
2. Before I fetch the models via xhr I prepend a few based on some configuration
3. When the xhr is resolved I need to replace any of the configuration models with the object coming back over the wire
4. this does appear to work because in memory I can see that my computed property only has 2 items, but my handlebars template seems to show 3 (one of the configuration models that was actually cut from the array after the xhr returned)

I verified the #'s above as follows

a.) In chrome dev tools I asked for

> App.Day.find(1).get('listings').get('length'); //returns 2 after the xhr

b.) Also I did the following

> App.Appointment.all().get('length'); //returns 2 after the xhr

** here is the code **

I have the following handlebars template (shows 3 items instead of 2)

```
{{#each appointment in day.listings}}
  {{appointment.start}}<br />
{{/each}}
```

The listings computed property on my day model looks like this

```
App.Day = DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr('string'),
      appointments: function() {
          return App.Appointment.find();
      }.property(),
      listings: function() {
          //pretend we need to add some values in memory before we fire the xhr ...
          App.Appointment.add({name: 'first'});

          return this.get('appointments');                                     
      }.property().volatile()
  });
```

The appointment model is an ember-data model but because I need to replace items in memory on the fly, I override the find method (and stub in my own add method to better controller the array)

```
  App.Appointment = DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr('string')
  }).reopenClass({
      records: [],                                                             
      find: function() {
          var self = this;
          self.records.clear();
          $.getJSON('/api/appointments/', function(response) {
              for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                  for(var j = 0; j < self.records.get('length'); j++) {
                      if (self.records[j].get('name') === response[i].name) {
                          //now that our xhr has finished we need to replace any that already exist
                          self.records.splice(j, 1);
                      }
                  }
              }
          });
          return this.records;
      },
      all: function() {
          return this.records;
      },
      add: function(record) {
          this.records.addObject(App.Appointment.createRecord(record));
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old answer deleted. Was way off base.

`splice` isn't KVO-compliant. `replace` is the ember-compliant method to use in its stead. CollectionView relies on the array mutation observers supported by `replace` to know what views to add and remove.

If this isn't the problem then I'll eat my hat.

Comment: so ... what does this dependent key you mention look like in code? just curious as I'm not sure where / what the syntax for this looks like

Comment: OK. I'm dumb. That's really not what's going on here, and adding that dependent key on the property will cause an infinite loop. I'm going to give this a bit more thought and then re-write my answer.

Comment: OK. So what I'm pretty sure is happening is that because `splice` isn't KVO compliant the collectionView isn't finding out that one of the elements has been removed. Try replacing `splice` with `replace`. Took me a bit too long to process that the array was being cleared, THEN the temporary model was added, and THEN it was cut out after being replaced.

Comment: What I don't get is how the replacement records are getting into the CV. All I see in your `find` method is the removing of records, but no adding...

Comment: nice -replace solved the issue exactly! thank you for taking the time to read through my complex setup (no jsfiddle either)